# Not able to start a Docker in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, sudo

```
ubuntu-gnome@ubuntu-gnome:~$ docker images

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.30/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied


ubuntu-gnome@ubuntu-gnome:~$ sudo docker images

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
ubuntu-gnome@ubuntu-gnome:~$
```

Comment: Is docker daemon running?

Comment: Earlier whenever I would run that command by default the deamon would execute but, I dont know what changed that it stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After install docker, it is not running by default. Assuming this is Ubuntu 16.04

You need to run below to start docker

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
```

And below to set it to start on boot

```
$ sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Comment: Thanks, but its a bit surprising. Earlier it would start by default. I dont know what changed? Please, can you help answering that?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether docker is running `$sudo systemctl status docker`

If it is not running then enable it using `$sudo systemctl enable docker` and start it using `$sudo systemctl start docker`